# AngularJS run() method in IFrame does not rerun on iframe reload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have a webpage with a `"Start Portal"` button and an iframe below it (on the same webpage) with id: `MyFrame`.

I get the URL of my angularjs based portal using jQuery AJAX and set the src of my iframe. Code for loading angularjs based portal is given below. The '`portalURL`' parameter contains the URL.

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: webmethodurl,
            data: {},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "JSONCallback",
            success: function(portalURL){
                $('#MyFrame').attr('src',portalURL);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

This works fine and my AngularJS portal open properly in the iframe.

But if I click the `"Start Portal"` button again, same AJAX code is called and I again get the AngularJS portal URL and it loads again. This works fine, but there is 1 issue.

I have some authentication code written in the AngilarJS `run()` method:

```
//Some initializing code before Angular invokes controllers
MyApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    ValidateSession();                   //1. First validate the session
}]);

function ValidateSession(){
    //this does some validation checks
}
```

Now, my issue is, this `run()` method is only called when I click the `"Start Portal"` for the first time. On subsequent clicks, it do reload the iframe with Portal URL from server side, but the angularjs `run()` method is never called again.

I tried to manually bootstrap the angular app, but could not make is work properly.

Somehow I want to kill or reload the whole the angularjs app if it was previously loaded and start fresh whenever iframe loads my angularjs portal.

I cannot make any modifications to iframe code, as in production that would be my client's website. I only have to provide them with angularjs portal url, which they will load using similar method I used.

Comment: it seems working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/VT5DUXgYN0ppXkJgaLvC?p=preview  (check console to see it's working). I also tried with cross domain by running 1 more domain in my PC, still could not reproduce the problem. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the iframe contents being loaded from the cache, you could append a random parameter to the `portalURL`:

```
success: function(portalURL) {
    // TODO: detect whether the portalURL already contains query string parameters
    // and use & instead of ?
    portalURL += '?v=' + (new Date()).getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    $('#MyFrame').attr('src', portalURL);
},
```

Comment: How do I miss the version logic. Thanks for the answer, I added a version to my PortalURL at the server side and it worked. I cannot make any change to IFRAME src javascript as its on my customer's website, but versioning helped me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved by controlling the browser behavior

To control browser caching for the iframe page from your web server either with HTTP headers or with  tags.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Anguarjs can control the way Angular App is being loaded but it has no control over iframe caching. Iframe is reloaded only when the whole page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but the other version logic helped me.